# Import error when calling "import tensorflow" in conda environment

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, anaconda3

I am trying to import TensorFlow using my Conda environment. I received the ImportError message below.
I tried to solve it by creating a new environment, installing TensorFlow 2, and trying with this new environment, but the error still appeared.

> It was work yesterday, and I don't know what is happen today.

```
**>>> import tensorflow**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Saja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ._api.v2 import compat
  File "C:\Users\Saja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "C:\Users\Saja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import compat
  File "C:\Users\Saja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "C:\Users\Saja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import math
  File "C:\Users\Saja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\math\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_math_ops import segment_sum_v2
**ImportError:** cannot import name 'segment_sum_v2' from 'tensorflow.python.ops.gen_math_ops' (C:\Users\Saja\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: @ack Adding the [tag:python] tag is useful, but removing the [tag:python-3.x] tag is not. I have generally voted to reject your recent edits because of this. Please don't be discouraged from adding the [tag:python] tag where it's missing, but keep the version tag, too (and probably try to improve the posts if you are proposing an edit anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a couple of days back. I would suggest you to download **Anaconda 2020.02** for a seamlessly smooth experience with **TensorFlow 2**.

After installation;

You can execute the following instructions and command to solve the issue: (do not include inverted commas)

Open Anaconda Prompt

type: `create --name py3-TF2.0 python = 3`

press `y` to continue After successful completion:

type `conda activate py3-TF2.0`

type `pip install matplotlib`

type `pip install tensorflow==2.3.0`

type `conda deactivate`

type `pip install ipykernel`

type `conda install nb_conda_kernels`

Now exit the Anaconda prompt and open the Anaconda Navigator application. Switch to `py3-TF2.0` from the base environment using the Environment tab. Install Jupyter in the specified environment. After successful installation, open Jupyter notebook and switch to `py3-TF2.0` kernel using Kernel Tab. You're good to go for using TensorFlow 2.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but I already have Conda version 22.9.0

Comment: I got this error when Install matplotlib ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 requires flatbuffers>=2.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 requires grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 requires libclang>=13.0.0, which is not installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.12,>=2.11.0, which is not installed. .................>*

Comment: Please, I do what you said. I faced another error which is: RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import